# how to pass an array to function in jquery jaudio

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

by using this function I tried to add several objects to temp array.

```js
var temp = [];

function addSong(id) {
    var button = $('#' + id + ''); // Button that triggered the modal
    var file = button.data('file'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
    var thumb = button.data('thumb'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
    var trackName = button.data('track_name'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
    var trackArtist = button.data('track_artist'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
    var trackAlbum = button.data('track_album'); // Extract info from data-* attributes

    temp += "{file:'" + file + "',thumb:'" + thumb + "',trackName:'" +
        trackName + "',trackArtist:'" + trackArtist + "',trackAlbum:'" + trackAlbum + "'},";

    $("#player").jAudio({
        playlist: []
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an array of objects not a string. Like the sample below

```
$("#player").jAudio({
    playlist: [{
        file: "resources/tracks/01.mp3",
        thumb: "resources/thumbs/01.jpg",
        trackName: "Track 1",
        trackArtist: "Artist 1",
        trackAlbum: "Album",
    }, {
        file: "resources/tracks/02.mp3",
        thumb: "resources/thumbs/02.jpg",
        trackName: "Track 2",
        trackArtist: "Artist 2",
        trackAlbum: "Album",
    }]
});
```

So change your temp variable to something like

```
var temp =  {
     file: file,
     thumb: thumb,
     trackName: trackName,
     trackArtist: trackArtist,
     trackAlbum: trackAlbum
 };
```

and then use it in the array

```
  $("#player").jAudio({
        playlist: [temp]
  });
```

Based on the updated question, you can modify your js function to something like this

```
 var temp = [];

 function addSong(id) {

     var button = $('#' + id + ''); // Button that triggered the modal
     var file = button.data('file'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
     var thumb = button.data('thumb'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
     var trackName = button.data('track_name'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
     var trackArtist = button.data('track_artist'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
     var trackAlbum = button.data('track_album'); // Extract info from data-* attributes

     var tempObj = {
         file: file,
         thumb: thumb,
         trackName: trackName,
         trackArtist: trackArtist,
         trackAlbum: trackAlbum
     };

     temp.push(tempObj);

     $("#player").jAudio({
         playlist: temp
     });
 }
```

Comment: yes I tried this one. It is working fine only for an one object. But I need to add more than one objects at same time. I create a function for that. above code was part of that function. when the function is called I want it to add data to temp array after the current object by keeping it's previous objects.

Comment: @UdaraSuranga Post the entire function.